# actix web test doesn't seem to be routing requests as expected

Tags: unit-testing, rust, actix-web

I recently updated to actix web 4, I had some tests that used the actix-web test module that stopped working as expected in the process. I'm sure it's something simple but I'm having trouble figuring out what changed. Here is a minimal example of the issue:

```
use actix_web::{test, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpRequest};

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn says_hello() {
  let req = test::TestRequest::get().uri("/index.html").to_request();
  let mut server =
    test::init_service(App::new().service(web::scope("/").route("index.html", web::get().to(|_req: HttpRequest| async {
      println!("Hello?");
      HttpResponse::Ok()
    })))).await;
  let _resp = test::call_and_read_body(&mut server, req).await;
}
```

running this test I would expect to see "Hello?" output to my console, however, the request handler function I have defined at "/index.html" doesn't seem to be called and I receive no output.

To be clear, the tests are more complicated and have assertions etc, this is just a working example of the main issue I am trying to resolve

actix-web = { version = "4.1.0", default-features = false }

---

note:

if I change all paths to the root path it will call the handler, I.E.

```
  let req = test::TestRequest::get().uri("/").to_request();
  let mut server =
    test::init_service(App::new().service(web::scope("/").route("/", web::get().to(|_req: HttpRequest| async {
      println!("Hello?");
      HttpResponse::Ok()
    })))).await;
  let _resp = test::call_and_read_body(&mut server, req).await;

  // prints "Hello?" to the console
```

However no other route combination I have tried calls the request handler.

Answer (score 2):

[Rust tests capture the output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#display-options) and only output them for failed tests.

If you want to show output on all tests you have to tell them to do so with either `testbinary --nocapture` or `cargo test -- --nocapture`.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of this, unfortunately, it has no effect on the issue I am experiencing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make things work by changing the path in the scope to an empty string

```
let req = test::TestRequest::get().uri("/index.html").to_request();
let mut server =
test::init_service(App::new().service(web::scope("").route("index.html", web::get().to(|_req: HttpRequest| async {
  println!("Hello?");
  HttpResponse::Ok()
})))).await;
let _resp = test::call_and_read_body(&mut server, req).await;

// prints "Hello?"
```